# logits and labels must be broadcastable, labels and logits dimension mismatch

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to Tensorflow and making a Multiclass Classifier. My dataset has 6 classes with images 150x150.
I am getting error regarding Mismatch of dimensions of Logits and Labels,

> I have seen other such questions on stackoverflow and my problem don't seem to be any of them.

Please anyone tell me what's the error, and also tell while constructing the I need not to tell batch size for output layer ( it's None if you see model.summary,it is automatically known later), so what things could affect it.?

The Error says:

```
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[40,6] labels_size=[10,6]
```

Model is defined as follows:

```
batch_size = 10
epochs = 100
IMG_HEIGHT = 150
IMG_WIDTH = 150
IMG_CHANNEL = 3
classes = 6



inputs = Input(shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3))
conv1 = Conv2D(96, 11, strides=(4,4) , padding='valid', activation='relu')(inputs)
pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding='valid', data_format=None)(conv1)
a = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tf.nn.local_response_normalization)
lrn1 = a(pool1)
conv2 = Conv2D(256, 5, padding='same', strides=(1,1) , activation='relu')(lrn1)
pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding='valid', data_format=None)(conv2)
b = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tf.nn.local_response_normalization)
lrn2 = b(pool2)
conv3 = Conv2D(384, 3, padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu')(lrn2)
conv4 = Conv2D(384, 3, padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu')(conv3)
conv5 = Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', strides=(1,1), activation='relu')(conv4)
conv6 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding='valid', data_format=None)(conv5)
flat1 = Flatten()(conv6)
dense1 = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(flat1)
drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(dense1)
dense2 = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(drop1)
drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(dense2)
dense3 = Dense(classes,activation='softmax')(drop2)


model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=dense3, name="one")

opt = SGD(lr=0.1, momentum=0.1)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])


# Generator Declaration
train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
                                              rescale=1./255,
                                              rotation_range=45,
                                              width_shift_range=.15,
                                              height_shift_range=.15,
                                              horizontal_flip=True,
                                              zoom_range=0.5
                                        ) # Generator for our training data

validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
                                         rescale=1./255
                                        ) # Generator for our validation data
train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(
                                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           class_mode='categorical',
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH)
                                                         )



val_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(  
                                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                                              directory=val_dir,
                                                              class_mode='categorical',
                                                            )

history = model.fit(
                              train_data_gen,
                              steps_per_epoch=3000//batch_size,
                              epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_data_gen,
                              validation_steps=3000//batch_size
                              )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using AlexNet, but on samll size images

If you are using AlexNet architecture on smaller images, you need to resize images or you have to do some changes in Pool and Stride hyperparameters, because with current shape something funcky happens in conv5 affecting the architecture.